# Unable to turn on computer

Tags: boot, laptop, hardware-failure

I have an old Acer Aspire 5737Z which I recently opened up in order to clean the fan because I was trying to solve an overheating problem. After screwing the parts together again I was unable to turn the computer on.

When I press the power button I can hear the computer or the fan working, and the power light lights up. The screen however, remains completely black and so does the hard disk led light. This is what it looks like: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA340.jpg). There is no initial launch screen or anything like that.

I have tried many things to fix this and searched a lot on the internet trying to find a solution. I have tried booting with each RAM seperately, I have tried tightening the hard drive screws and I have tried removing some parts separately. I am no expert at computer building or computer hardware so I do not really know what the probable cause of the problem is (though from what I have read it seems like a defect motherboard may be the issue). Anyway, I would be really grateful for any help.

Note: I know that there is a lot of similar questions to this one, but trust me, I have read every single one I could find without any luck.

Edit: I have also tried connecting the computer to an external screen unsurprisingly without luck. As mentioned the hard disk light does not light so I do not believe there is anything wrong with the screen.

Comment: which parts did you remove and put back again?

Comment: @golimar It's been some weeks now so I don't really remember

Comment: Try to start with only CPU, one stick RAM, and monitor ONLY; no usb devices, no HDD, no cards, etc.  Then add devices one by one. Starting and turning off between each.